# Peer org1 could not join the channel

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

```
Peer Org1 could not join the channel.

Hide error details
the grpc web client timed out the proposal after 25.0 secs: (stitch) timeout waiting for grpc web proxy response
```

**In this, im using IBM blockchain cloud plotform... But i'm getting thhis error while joining the channel please anyone help me**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the peer to the consortium before adding it to the channel?